# no signals is displayed on monitor

Tags: motherboard

I installed a new CPU in my PC, but when I turn on the machine the fans start, but the monitor gets no signal.The sound of beep is comes, and the computer does not restart automatically (i read that for some people it does)

- mother board: H61
- power supply: 300W (stock HP)
- old CPU: Intel i3
- new CPU: i5 3rd gen 3470

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the actual motherboard - H61 is an Intel chipset - or brand/model of the PC itself if applicable as well as the exact characteristics of the original CPU.

Comment: Could be it was bad. Could be you put it in backwards. Could be PS is to small. Could be you left out a plug. could be...

Comment: When you put the old CPU back in does the computer boot properly? Standard hardware diagnostics steps really require you to swap things out and keep trying. Also, mainboards will often use specific beep codes or some other way to communicate specific error states. Look up your mainboard's manual to check what it is trying to tell you. If you still don't know what's going on at that point, add all that info to this question so we can help further. Right now there is not enough info for us to help.